# Connect PC to Android phone with WiFi Direct

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I want to connect PC with Android phone using WiFi Direct.
Then I want to pass messages between these two. Anyway I have no idea how to connect my pc with android device. I already write code for pass messages between two android devices using wifi direct. I want to extend that into pass messages between pc and android device. My pc running Ubuntu 14.04..
Is there any idea or sample to do that?

Please Help me.